# AngularJS - How to clear query text in input of ui-select multiple options

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-select

I am using ui-select(version - 0.11.2), my `HTML` code follows:

```
<ui-select ng-model="staff.selected" ng-disabled="disabled" reset-search-input="false" multiple>
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Staff">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="staff in staffs" refresh="refreshStaff($select.search)" refresh-delay="0">
        <div ng-bind-html="name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Here I am using `multiple` to select multi options. After I searched for query on type it's remains showing. How can I shouldn't show that?

`JS` code

```
$scope.refreshStaff = function(name) {
  Staffs.query($scope.queryCriteria).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ui-select ... reset-search-input="true">
```

Comment: And explanation for why this works would improve your answer.

Comment: Thank you Timur for your answer